# how to bind country change intl tel input

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, intl-tel-input

I using country code plugin name **[intlTelInput.js](https://intl-tel-input.com/)**
  (this I demo page)
in the page I want to empty the phone *(input filed)* when country select change

```
<div class="demo">
    <h3>Demo</h3>
    <div class="iti iti--allow-dropdown">
        <div class="iti__flag-container">
            <div class="iti__selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="country-listbox" tabindex="0"
                title="Algeria (&#8235;الجزائر&#8236;&lrm;): +213">
                <div class="iti__flag iti__dz"></div>
                <div class="iti__arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div><input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-intl-tel-input-id="0"
            placeholder="0551 23 45 67">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
$(".iti__selected-flag").bind('change', function(event) {
         $('#phone').val('')
      });
```

And 
below code will make phone filed value empty *(when click , but I want it empty when after select another country item done)*

```
$(function(){
      $("#phone").bind('change', function(event) {
         $('#phone').val('')
      });
    })
```

But it not working

Comment: `bind` change on a `div` !

Comment: $(function(){
      $("#phone").bind('change', function(event) {
         $('#phone').val('')
      });
    })                                                                //not work when bind on id also

Comment: Both are wrong way, you trying to bind change on `select` but you tried to bind `div` or `phone`, you should bind `select`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a native way to bind country change **[intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)**:

```
var input = $("#phone");
input.intlTelInput();

input.on("countrychange", function() {
  input.val('')
});
```

Comment: What if I don't use Jquery?

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone1");        
   window.intlTelInput(input, {        
     initialCountry: "In", //change according to your own country.      
     utilsScript: "assets/js/utils.js",        
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it