# On change event for country code in intlTelInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am trying to set onchange event in intlTelInput (jQuery). But it's not working . If I change country code then it will listen as change . Here is my code. It's working when I change mobile number. But I want it when I change country code. Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" name="user_phone_number" id="user_phone_number"> 

$('input[name=user_phone_number]').change(function() {
     var countryCode = $("#user_phone_number").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
     alert(countryCode);
            
 });
```

Comment: Please define "_it's not working_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the documentation, you can use

```
input.addEventListener("countrychange", function() {
  // do something with iti.getSelectedCountryData()
});
```

and try this s[olution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034134/how-to-bind-country-change-intl-tel-input) also

```
var input = $("#user_phone_number");
input.intlTelInput();

input.on("countrychange", function() {
  input.val('')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to change selection by country ID

```
$('#user_phone_number').intlTelInput("setCountry", "us");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, worked for me:

```
$("#ElementId").on("countrychange", function () {
                var SelectedCountry = $("#ElementId").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData");
                console.log(SelectedCountry );
           });
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function.   I already added plugins link and jquery link